# What does (001) Silicon mean?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals

If someone gives me a thin film of Si, and they tell me it's (001) Si, does that mean that the (001) planes of Si are the ones making up the surface of the film?

Comment: Here is some information on Miller Indices that should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The surface of the film is a [001] plane through the silicon (or diamond) lattice, space group Fd-3m (#227),

[image: Si [001] plane]